# How to access UserControl's DataContext from another UserControl?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm working on a legacy application that's written using Silverlight 5, The application contains lot's of anti-patterns and bad practices. I'm responsible for adding real-time interactions (such as notification) using SingalR.
By the way, They're using [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.applicationservices(v=vs.91).aspx) WCF RIA Services for interacting with authentication.

They have a Main page, this page is the place where I'm getting user's notification and show them for logged in users:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       //...

    }
}
```

So as you can see I didn't set DataContext property as long as user is logged in, I need to set MainPage's DataContext after a user logs in to application, So I have to do that in [LoginOperation_Completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.operationbase.completed(v=vs.91).aspx) inside `LoginForm` page:

```
public partial class LoginForm : StackPanel
{
   private LoginRegistrationWindow parentWindow;
   private LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();
   public LoginForm()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       //...
   }

   private void LoginOperation_Completed(LoginOperation loginOperation)
   {

    if (loginOperation.LoginSuccess)
    {
            // Here I need to access MainPages's DataContext property and set it with my ViewModel
    }
   }
}
```

Now my question is that, how can I set MainPage's DataContext property inside another class (in this case `LoginFrom`)?

I have also tried to give an ID to my MainPage user control and access it like this:

```
mainPage.DataContext = new NotificationItemViewModel();
```

But the compiler gives me this error:

> The name 'mainPage' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Please, Add your XAML

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/SirwanAfifi/c329af5029db2a8e3f51) the XAML for MainPage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out How to solve my question, There is a simple way to achieve this, I should have created the static instance of the `MainPage` class in the class itself:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public static MainPage Instance { get; private set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

Now I can access to the MainPage's DataContext this way:

```
MainPage.Instance.DataContext = new NotificationItemViewModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your `MainPage` UserControl where you pasted it in `LoginForm` XAML. Not in the definition of `MainPage`.

Comment: Properties are inside MainPage so why should I name LoginForm?

Comment: Not, you do not need to name `LoginForm`. You need to name instance of `MainPage` in XAML of `LoginForm`. Now, you just to name `UserControl` in description of `MainPage`.
If you don't understand, show me your XAML of `LoginForm` and I help you.

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/SirwanAfifi/e72acb67af8c2034010f) the XAML of the LoginForm. Can you explain How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I do not expect it, but where you placed your controls? Ok, You describe `LoginForm` control and `MainPage` control. But It is not related together. Do you have some container for something else? Where do you place it like instance? I just wanna tell you, that when you add ` Name="mainPage"` in `MainPage.cs.xaml` it's mean that you can use it in `MainPage.cs.xaml` or `MainPage.cs`. Not in LoginForm.cs